# What can be done to make a Youtube video play properly upon the first attempt to view it?

Tags: youtube

What can be done to make a Youtube video play properly upon the first attempt to view it?

Most of the time I get dark areas as shown for example in the attached: 
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/05/28/ytquestion.png

Answer (score 0):

Update your flash player. That is probably corrupt.